# Laravel: "Failed to open stream' in storage/views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I had my Laravel 3 application running on a different server. I wrapped it up and sent it to my new server. Unpacked it, and while I am trying to display the Laravel application on the new server, I receive this error:

> Unhandled Exception Message:
>
> file_put_contents(/var/www/customer_area/storage/views/13f378cf44cd9253eb03394b5a7fd914):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> Location:
>
> /var/www/customer_area/laravel/blade.php on line 63

I have already read through this question several times where others have solved a similar problem by changing permissions on 'storage/directories' to '775'. I even changed permissions on the entire 'var/www' directory to '777', and I still have the error.

Something that I noticed is that there is no '13f378cf44cd9253eb03394b5a7fd914' in the storage/views folder. There are five other files in the folder, but not that one.

Comment: I got it to work by changing the permissions on 'storage/views' to '777'. However, I realize that something must be messed up with my ownership. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running apache on linux, look into recursive chgrp www-data and chown www-data on the folders

Answer (score 0):

Just modify file/folder permissions
Assuming you are in root folder, run one of these commands

```
chmod -R 0777 storage // for L3
chmod -R 0777 app/storage // for L4
```